# Flex based UML designer

Tags: apache-flex, uml

Does anyone know of any flex based (preferably open source) framework or component to edit UML?  I was looking for something like gliffy.com, however that will not let you export to an XMI file.

Comment: I'm assuming you want Flex based framework because you want to include it in to your own Flex based application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of googleing, it looks like what I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

We are going to release soon [UML4AS - UML for ActionScript and Flex](http://www.uml4as.com). It supports bi-directional code synchronization for .as and .mxml files.

It doesn't have for the moment an export to XMI option. You could request it as a new feature on our site.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the Opensource UML Tool which supports XML exporting option.
[Check it out](http://bouml.free.fr/features.html)

Comment: That looks to be along the lines of what I need, however I need something based in flex

Comment: Guess you can add eclipse plugins to FLEX also check this out
http://www.idefactory.com/userguide/doc/as2uml.html

Comment: I'm actually looking for something to have a flex interface to design and export UML.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there are no open source Flex based UML Tools. I think you should build on and open it up to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CrocusModeller - UML for Flex and AS](http://crocusmodeller.com).